# Dynamic List with Button in only one row in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, listview, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I want to make a screen in react native which contains a dynamic listview [Listview but only one row contains a button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOrSj.png) . I am using native base library for making the UI of the screen in that various ListView Components are given but how to make this type of listview is not given. I have searched a lot but I could not find any library with this type of Listview .

If anyone can suggest a way to design this type of listview it would be a really great help . Thanks in advance !!

Here is my code implementation

```
export default class AddNewMember extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      registerButtonClicked: false
    }
  }

  registerButtonClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      registerButtonClicked: true
    })
  }
  _renderRow = () => {
    var items = [
      'Simon Mignolet',
      'Nathaniel Clyne',
      'Dejan Lovren',
      'Mama Sakho',
      'Emre Can'
    ]
    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
      if (items[i] === 'Simon Mignolet') {
        return (
          <ListItem style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ marginLeft: 25 }}>Vikas</Text>
          </ListItem>
        )
      } else {
        return (
          <ListItem style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <Text style={{ marginLeft: 25 }}>{items[i]}</Text>
          </ListItem>
        )
      }
    }
  }
  CardHeader = () => {
    var items = [
      'Simon Mignolet',
      'Nathaniel Clyne',
      'Dejan Lovren',
      'Mama Sakho',
      'Emre Can'
    ]

    if (this.state.registerButtonClicked) {
      return (
        <List
          style={{ marginTop: 12, flex: 1 }}
          dataArray={items}
          renderRow={item => (
            <ListItem>
              <Text style={{ marginLeft: 25 }}>{item}</Text>
            </ListItem>
          )}
        />
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Content>
         /* <Card transparent>
            <CardItem>
              <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row', flex: 0 }}>
                <Text style={styles.participant_name}>
                  Harish Venkatesh
                </Text>

                <TouchableOpacity
                  onPress={() => this.registerButtonClick()}
                >
                  <Text
                    style={{
                      fontSize: 12,
                      marginLeft: 30,
                      letterSpacing: 0,
                      lineHeight: 16,
                      height: 20,
                      marginTop: 10,

                      width: 250
                    }}
                  >
                    Register New Player
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              </View>
            </CardItem>
          </Card>*/
          <List
            style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 12 }}
            dataArray={items}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}
          />
        </Content>
      )
    }
  }

  text = () => {
    if (this.state.registerButtonClicked) {
      return (
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 14,
            color: '#951b1f',
            letterSpacing: 0,
            lineHeight: 20,
            textAlign: 'left',
            marginLeft: 30,
            marginBottom: 12,
            marginTop: 30
          }}
        >
          Add New Participant
        </Text>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Text
          style={{
            fontSize: 14,
            color: '#000000',
            letterSpacing: 0,
            lineHeight: 20,
            textAlign: 'left',
            marginLeft: 30,
            marginBottom: 12,
            marginTop: 30
          }}
        >
          PARTICIPANTS DETAILS{' '}
        </Text>
      )
    }
  }

  registerCardorAddDetailsCard = () => {
    if (this.state.registerButtonClicked) {
      return (
        <Card style={{ flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }} cardBody>
          <Item
            style={{
              marginLeft: 27
            }}
          >
            <Icon active name="person-add" />
            <Input
              style={{
                fontSize: 17,
                color: '#000000',
                letterSpacing: 0
              }}
              placeholder="Participant Name"
            />
          </Item>{' '}
          <Item
            style={{
              marginLeft: 27
            }}
          >
            <Icon active name="calendar" />
            <Input
              style={{
                fontSize: 17,
                color: '#000000',
                letterSpacing: 0
              }}
              placeholder="Date of Birth"
              keyboardType="numeric"
            />
          </Item>{' '}
          <Item
            style={{
              marginLeft: 27
            }}
          >
            <Icon active name="calendar" />
            <Input
              style={{
                fontSize: 17,
                color: '#000000',
                letterSpacing: 0
              }}
              placeholder="Email address"
              keyboardType="email-address"
            />
          </Item>
        </Card>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Card cardBody>
          {' '}
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 17,
              marginLeft: 20,
              marginTop: 15,
              marginBottom: 15,
              color: '#000000',
              letterSpacing: 0,
              opacity: 0.5
            }}
          >
            +91-8840415633
          </Text>
          <Separator />
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 17,
              color: '#000000',
              letterSpacing: 0,
              marginLeft: 27,
              marginTop: 15,
              marginBottom: 15,
              opacity: 0.5
            }}
          >
            30 Dec 1994
          </Text>
          <Separator />
          <Item
            style={{
              marginLeft: 27
            }}
          >
            <Input
              style={{
                fontSize: 17,
                color: '#000000',
                letterSpacing: 0
              }}
              placeholder="harishvenkatesh@ontroapp.com"
            />
          </Item>
        </Card>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        {this.CardHeader()} {this.text()}
        {this.registerCardorAddDetailsCard()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

here in _renderRow function I am trying to do conditional rendering but still not got successful.

Comment: You should provide code of your current implementation

Comment: Ok wait I am editing my post

Comment: I have edited my post please have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest approach would be to use index of the item that is being rendered.

```
_renderRow = (rowData, secId, rowId) => {
  if (rowId === 0) {
    // your custom list item, renders only for first row
    return (
      <ListItem style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text style={{ marginLeft: 25 }}>Vikas</Text>
      </ListItem>
    )
  }
  return (
    <ListItem style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Text style={{ marginLeft: 25 }}>{rowData}</Text>
    </ListItem>
  )
}
```

NativeBase's `List` component uses `ListView` component under the hood, so you can take a look at its documentation here http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow

> This part below is just general suggestion and my IMHO

In general, I would suggest you to use FlatList, as ListView was deprecated, and FlatList is much more performant. And moreover, I would suggest to avoid using UI libraries like NativeBase, whenever you can, as their components are usually wrapped version of native components presented by React Native, with some defaults, which might make your life easier in the beginning, but it stops you from learning real structure and components, and later you won't be able to create more complex components, and there is no available library for you.

> Edit per your comments

In your code, you are not sending rowData, rowId to you _renderRow function

You should pass those to this._renderRow as below.

```
<List style={{ marginTop: 12, }} dataArray={items} renderRow={(item, sectionID, rowID) => this._renderRow(item, sectionId, rowId)}> </List>
```

or you could just do it like this

```
<List style={{ marginTop: 12, }} dataArray={items} renderRow={this._renderRow}> </List>
```

Comment: hey I have made changes in my code accordingly u have suggested me but I am getting blank rows

Comment: try to log parameters that are passed to _renderRow function (rowData, secId, rowId). Are they being logged? are the values as expected(rowData should be your items, rowId should be index)?

Comment: this is the github link of the two functions which I have changed                    <script src="https://gist.github.com/bvnbbn/af7319b787ca5268996159b1865ff233.js"></script>

Comment: bvnbbn / gist:af7319b787ca5268996159b1865ff233

Comment: <List style={{ marginTop: 12, }} dataArray={items}
                    renderRow={(item, sectionID, rowID) => this._renderRow()}>
                </List>

Comment: I am calling function _renderRow like this and I am getting undefined in item and rowid in function _renderRow

Answer (score 0):

You can please learn about condition rendering.
This way you can possible to make your requirement.

https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html

Comment: Can you tell on what property of ListView I can apply conditional rendering

Comment: you can modify the renderRow property.